# Replacing Names in a List

Tags: excel, vba

I want to automate deidentifying the names in an Excel sheet. An example screenshot is shown below. The number of rows and columns will be variable within the sheet. I am familiar with inserting a button into Excel, but I am unaware of the best way to cycle through the entire sheet & search for each cell with the same name and replace the name with a pseudonym. The number needs to be left unchanged. The format of name, number, name, number will always be the same so a counter that adds 2 to the row index each time should take care of that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Original Excel Sheet Format

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Non-VBA Solution

Assuming the first two column range is "A1:B10" and destination range id "D1:E10" on "Sheet1"

Copy the original data from "A1:B10" to "D1:E10".

Select First Column "A1:A10" --> Goto special --> Constants and Text --> Copy and paste on other Sheet (say Sheet2 Cell A1). Similarly, select special and copy "B1:B10" below the earlier pasted column A values on the other sheet.

So it will look like this.

[image]

Select this range and remove duplicates with Data Menu --> Data Tools --> Remove duplicates.

On "Sheet1", Select destination range "D1:D10" --> Goto special --> Constants and Text --> Enter formula with Control+Enter

```
="Student_"&MATCH(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$7,0)
```

On "Sheet1", Select destination range "E1:E10" --> Goto special --> Constants and Text --> Enter formula with Control+Enter

```
="Student_"&MATCH(B1,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$7,0)
```

*Note the formula difference in reference A1 and B1*

Copy destination range "D1:E10" and paste special values.

[image]

This works because desired result is Bob(A1) is Student_1 and Sam(A3) is Student_2. It will fail in case of desired result Bob(A1) as Student_1 and Robert(B1) as Student_2. If this is going to be a frequent procedure record macro.

Answer (score 0):

### Create Generic Names

[image]

- Copy the code into a standard module (e.g. `Module1`).
- Adjust the values in the **const**ants section including `wb`.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub createGeneric()

    ' Constants
    Const srcName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const srcFirst As String = "A1"
    Const tgtName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const tgtFirst As String = "E1"
    Const Generic As String = "Student_"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    ' Write values from Source Range to Data Array.
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = wb.Worksheets(srcName).Range(srcFirst).CurrentRegion

    ' Modify values in Data Array.
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, g As Long, Current As Variant
    For j = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
        For i = 1 To UBound(Data)
            Current = Data(i, j)
            If Not IsEmpty(Current) Then
                If Not IsNumeric(Current) Then
                    If Not dict.exists(Current) Then
                        g = g + 1
                        dict(Current) = Generic & g
                    End If
                    Data(i, j) = dict(Current)
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    Next j

    ' Write values from Data Array to Target Range.
    wb.Worksheets(tgtName).Range(tgtFirst) _
      .Resize(UBound(Data), UBound(Data, 2)).Value = Data

    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Data transformed.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```